# bbding seems not to be completely transmitted via tex4ebook does not show all signs in epub

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook, bbding

Since I like to make the end of a book with a nice looking end-sign to close the text finally and visually, I want to use the package `bbding`. But my choosen sign is not visible in the epub done by tex4ebook when viewed in Adobe Digital Edition laptop version. The following shows a little MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\begin{document}
    
    Package bbding use in \TeX4ebook:\\ 
    \verb+\AsteriskCenterOpen+: \AsteriskCenterOpen \quad will not be shown in epub \\
    \verb+\EightStarTaper+: \EightStarTaper \quad will be shown in epub, but not so nice\\
    \verb+\AsteriskThinCenterOpen+: \AsteriskThinCenterOpen \quad will not be shown in epub
    
    Package bbding does work with pdflatex but not completely right with \TeX4ebook. Why?

\end{document}
```

Is the problem a systematic problem with tex4ebook or with Adobe Digital Edition laptop version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbols used by `bbding` are supported by TeX4ht, but it outputs Unicode characters for them. I can see the result in Calibre, but it is possible that your Epub reader doesn't have a font that supports them. In this case, you can convert these symbols to pictures. Try this file, `bbding.4ht`:

```
\NewConfigure{bbding}{2}

\def\:tempa#1{\a:bbding\o:@chooseSymbol:{#1}\b:bbding}
\HLet\@chooseSymbol\:tempa
\Configure{bbding}{\Picture+{}}{\EndPicture}
\endinput
```

It attaches TeX4ht instructions for the picture conversion to the `\@chooseSymbol` command. This command is used by `bbding` to print symbols.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Michal. Beautiful. That works both in Calibre and Adobe Digital Edition now for me. Will you integrate this in tex4ebook as an automatic detection?

Comment: @Thomkrates I will probably not integrate this, as the Unicode solution is preferable. I've used pictures in this case only because of the lack of support for these characters in ebook readers, but for example in browsers it works fine.